# What is the unit of canvas.width or canvas.height?

Tags: android, canvas

Android documentation states that canvas.getWidth() or .height() returns the width/height of the canvas but the unit is not stated.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#getWidth()

I couldn't find anywhere about its unit. When I try to use it as pixels I can't achieve the result as expected.

Question: What is the unit of canvas.width or canvas.height?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would expect that to be in pixels. Usually, if it does not say otherwise, it is in pixels.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm, it's pixels!

Comment: For my observation it is in PostScript points (1/72th of an inch)

Answer (score 0):

The guide states this in the printing custom documents section

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs#draw-content

> When using Canvas to draw on a PDF page, elements are specified in
> points, which is 1/72 of an inch. Make sure you use this unit of
> measure for specifying the size of elements on the page. For
> positioning of drawn elements, the coordinate system starts at 0,0 for
> the top left corner of the page.